# Spree Commerce/Marketplace - with Braintree Config (Stripe errors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, braintree

Using the spree commerce setup and I have completed the following gem installs and done the necessary bundle installs and server restarts.

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content'
gem 'spree_drop_ship', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship'
gem 'spree_marketplace', github: 'dennisluan/spree_marketplace'
gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
```

Although the admin side allows me to configure the test for 'payment methods' and I have used Braintree keys for this.

So now when I go to admin / suppliers and try to create a new supplier I get two messages

1. configure stripe API (but this errors doesn't show now - and error 2 below keeps coming up)
2. Stripe::InvalidRequestError at /admin/suppliers Recipients have been deprecated and are no longer available. They have been replaced by managed accounts (see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts), which you should use if you're creating a new platform. Please contact support@stripe.com if you have any questions. (The link is the original stripe request setup for marketplace -
   https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_marketplace )

I have also read further documents to go to /app/models/spree/gateway/ - to configure this also I dont have this folder structure.

Would like to understand how to amend this error and point to braintree.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and if more info is required - I can update the question.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never used the spree_drop_ship with a combination of spree_marketplace, but it seems that it is capable of handling payment gateways as well. Are you defining the payment gateways and assigning them to the suppliers correctly?

Comment: It appears that the [`spree_marketplace`](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_marketplace) gem supports only Stripe. From the README: _"Mainly all that really means is that this extension enables sending payments to your drop ship suppliers through Stripe with their payment service."_

Comment: @AdamPaca    - so would it be best to remove dropship and then configure braintree. 
In the suppliers tab I do not have the options to assign the payment gateway. I only have the options to configure types of payment gateways under the payment methods.

Comment: @AdamPaca so I will try a new fresh rails instance with braintree and marketplace.  Without using dropship..  Is it possible to use braintree instead of stripe?